# Proof implication with exist in the premises without using Isar

Tags: isabelle, proof

I have the following goal extracted from one of the theorems I have to prove:

```
∃ys zs. [x] = ys @ zs ∧ P ys zs ⟹ P [] [x] ∨ P [x] []
```

Here I wanted to apply the existential elimination rule but  it produces two strange subgoals:

```
 1. ∃ys zs. [x] = ys @ zs ∧ P ys zs ⟹ ∃x. ?P25 x
 2. ⋀xa. ∃ys zs. [x] = ys @ zs ∧ P ys zs ⟹ ?P25 xa ⟹ P [] [x] ∨ P [x] []
```

The idea is that if I could remove the quantifiers  the proof is indeed quite easy. If [x]= ys @ zs then there are two possibilities. Either ys = [x], zs = [] or the opposite. Thus, we would P [x] [] or P [] [x].

How can I prove this without using Isar, only using apply commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the exists elimination tactic fails in your case, but the following line succeeds.

```
by (elim exE, rename_tac ys zs, case_tac ys, auto)
```

Here, the rename_tac renames the newly obtained lists to the user-chosen names `ys` and `zs`, so that afterwards a case-analysis on `ys` (empty or not) is possible.

Comment: great thank you for your answer. in order to explain why my approach fails, you may want to add that im using rule command and this command will return the premises unified. in order to eliminate the existential probably i could use erule. (i say this just for completeness of your answer). Thanks again!

Comment: in fact combination of erule exE with case_tac ys and auto solves the goalç